# Why floating div starts at the header section

Tags: html, css

My content div that overlaps the header div in my CSS code as per the attached image. Both the content and side-nav divs should be below the header section.

[image]

I tried changing the value of position property for the elements but it doesn't work. I also tried introducing top property to the content section to be as same as the side nav but it didn't work too

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  line-height: 1.7;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #777;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  background-color: orangered;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 75em) {
  .container {
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.header {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  height: 8vh;
  background-color: #3394e3;
  border-bottom: var(--line);
  top: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  /*
              display: flex;
              justify-content: space-between;
              align-items: center;*/
}

.side-nav {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0px auto;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  top: 8vh;
  clear: both;
  background-color: #fff;
  bottom: 0;
}

.content {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  min-height: 93vh;
  width: 85%;
  float: right;
}

.footer {
  background-color: green;
  height: 7vh;
  width: 85%;
  float: right;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header-fixed">
    <header class="header">

    </header>
  </div>
  <nav class="side-nav">
  </nav>
  <main class="content">
  </main>
  <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `.header` has a `position:fixed` which takes it out of the normal flow of a webpage. So since it is taken out (essentially placed on a different layer of the page flow), your content is relatively positioned in the normal flow. As the `.header` is taken out of the flow, the `.content` is technically the first item in the flow of the page now.

So you will just need to give the `.content` a `margin-top` that is equivalent to the height of your `.header`.

Your `.sidebar` also has a `position:fixed`, so it's on a different layer, so it doesn't care about where it is placed in relation to the `.header`. So that's why you had to manually position it and give it a `top:8vh` to put it 8vh down from the top of the window.